# Imgur API: all requests failing with 429 Unknown (this is their code for over rate limit)

Tags: oauth, imgur

Starting yesterday morning between 10-11am, Imgur started failing all API requests with 429 Unknown. This is their code for being over the rate limit. It happens even with a freshly created app, so I am definitely not breaking any rate limit. (I send maybe 20 requests a day anyway.)

It happens even when getting an authorization token, so I can't, for example, get a token then check a different endpoint.

In the requests headers, I get

```
"x-post-rate-limit-limit"          => "1250",
"x-post-rate-limit-remaining"      => "0",
"x-post-rate-limit-reset"          => "-1",
```

That seems to say that I have 0 requests left, and "rate limit reset" being -1, I am guessing means never. Have I been IP banned or something? What is going on here?

I send the requests from a dedicated server. It is the only IP using my app, so it can't be overlap.

---

Update: I am able to make the same requests from my home computer, using both my own functions and Postman. I guess this looks like an IP ban from Imgur then?

Comment: It's happening to me too, although I've been sending a lot more than 20 requests a day. But it was running fine for 5 months and then suddenly this.